# How To Associate A Long List Of ID To Img By Running Multiple Requests One After The Other And Scrape Urls That Load Data From Authenticated Fetch XHR

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, axios, puppeteer, cheerio

I have a list of id to associate the corresponding img. Normally I would use Node.js Axios Cheerio to run multiple requests one after the other like `HipHopHuman` solved [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/hhntsx/axios_how_to_run_multiple_requests_one_after_the/)

By the way there are websites that load data in the browser by using unauthenticated XHR so one in the comments told to call the Fetch endpoint directly. But when those Fetch/XHR are authenticated, one told a solution would be using [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/)

Since my goal is to run multiple requests one after the other so to log the id and corresponding img each line

```sql
030175020 null
800077125 <img src="//farmacialoreto.it/image/data/quarz-d30-weleda-polvere-20g.jpg" alt="Quarz D30 Weleda 20g">
                                    <span class="sale">-1%</span>
```

I am stuck here you see after the first result true then data log the same for the whole loop

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const baseUrl = 'https://farmacialoreto.it/#/dfclassic/query='
const arr = ["030175020","800075590","800077125","800077125","800078685","800079434","800106585","800130573","800131017","800166769","800175008","800196824","800196851","800202501","800202855","800218505","800218594","800219457","800225904","800238457","800240246","800242190","800243331","800243432","800244384","800246225","800246643","800246656","800249308","800251504","800254219","800262572","800282636","800408155","800473997","800586048","800590299","800590655","800591620","800596037","800619239","800624482","800636351","800640880","800641375","800641817","800649966","800650196","800650804","800652291","800652859","800659120","800678587","800680478","800697649","800697690","800698108","800713493","800713505","800715866","800716021","800720118","800728382","800890889","800916684","801106461","801216831","801229598","801229636","801281864","801290382","801451345","801548518","801812013","802118430","900727379","900728181","901133482","901155162","902104847","902104850","902260470","902552001","902580846","902583145","902583234","902682107","902893460","902990668","903450031","903609636","903960161","903989414","904249416","904312182","904424660","904548106","904616327","905006351","905006464","905215341","906585587","906595196","906957459","906957485","906957547","906957687","907174104","908017940","908371166","908371279","908403126","909301552","911172308","911177018","912651510","913516542","913765436","920327436","920653565","921563437","921811699","921890808","922374107","922472143","922492766","925497935","925774453","925856357","926243229","926461308","927043657","927220259","927288718","930511542","930771821","931077109","931570523","932511672","932708771","933161642","933532929","934729435","934729486","934843828","934849959","934850126","935016826","935360519","935526588","936008364","938470174","938909761","938990948","939014852","939305381","939631952","939631964","941782385","942274212","942275076","942316441","942683362","942816024","942819145","942853375","942869811","942890397","942941776","942975867","942979838","943088652","943112540","943229878","943284063","943315085","943778187","943798759","943908905","943922207","944020801","944034661","944166141","944183437","944257447","944262070","944265053","944270331","944313081","944313131","944396579","944446285","944531060","944619030","944702190","944768415","944785157","944792377","944792415","944792427","944854936","944877745","944911724","944959992","945030815","945030827","945184897","947241016","970297937","970297949","970521213","971007505","971125075","971135468","971633995","971810369","972070890","972153771","972153783","972165308","972282836","972499444","972660219","973282383","973343926","973592429","973645017","973729825","973846847","973993746","973999485","974015214","974094221","974167797","974367029","974386157","974405223","974844096","974844108","974844110","974844122","974844134","974844146","974844173","974890358","974890992","974891069","974917635","974917647","974967681","974990501","974994168","975019961","975037920","975045485","975062858","975062860","975207883","975431444","975581051","975581063","975759604","975896453","975984562","976002648","976002651","976005316","976007753","976011116","976289470","976595090","976733737","976777514","976782540","976836445","976920633","977075338","977257144","977258870","977433287","977471325","977705437","977805338","977808094","977808284","977822497","977822509","977822511","978254593","978279519","978507376","978599114","978599189","978691576","978850978","978851590","978852022","978868267","978868937","978919619","978974273","979016589","979044979","979045123","979046632","979092246","979095926","979097514","979255344","979333301","979359015","979683606","979683618","979683620","979683632","979683671","979683683","979683758","979683760","979683784","979683834","979683861","979683873","979683897","979683911","979683950","979683962","979683974","979798030","979798055","979843570","980189082","980189094","980189118","980189120","980189132","980295950","980435085","980445302","980463448","980479695","980495547","980516557","980531370","980638631","980638643","980777181","980786711","980787016","980809343","980809368","980810271","980810283","980810358","980834511","980860187","980860199","980907012","980907024","980907671","980907695","980911604","981060597","981071083","981085018","981111230","981143959","981152945","981259904","981259928","981346354","981358548","981396361","981397185","981397235","981416074","981441987","981449604","981451242","981470154","981471333","981490129","981499256","981504602","981592239","981622549","981928753","981930365","981971221","981979242","981979317","981998964","982010050","982053910","982143481","982143493","982144178","982391258","982411237","982445379","982461446","982461459","982461473","982470318","982470662","982483618","982510897","982512461","982514364","982544443","982657999","982668182","982668194","982738914","982738926","982754018","982775037","982816023","982816276","982902076","982932194","982935266","982935292","982935304","982981490","983031889","983040104","983199819","983278159","983278173","983278185","983278197","983278211","983282409","983322431","983533946","983757737"]

async function relateCodeToImg() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true })
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  for (const id of arr) {
    await page.goto(`${baseUrl}${id}`)
    
    if (await page.$eval('span[data-role="total"]', e => e.innerText) === "1") {
      console.log(id + " " + await page.$eval('figure[class="df-card__image image"]', e => e.innerHTML))
    } else {
      console.log(id + " " + null);
    }
    
  }
  await browser.close()
}
relateCodeToImg()
```

Comment: Looks like client-side code is loading the data and rendering html in the browser.  The base html you get does not contain the data.  You would have to have something to execute the javascript and let it perform the request for the actual data.  In chrome, open dev tools and go to the the Network tab and reload the page.  Click on 'Fetch/XHR' and you will see a url like this which returns the actual list: https://www.efarma.com/efarmacatalog/productattributes/loadajax?productSku=000590051&_=1671901482258

Comment: This data is probably added dynamically by JS. What output are you trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

Using `puppeteer`

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function getData(url) {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(url);

        const titles = await page.evaluate(() => {
            const images = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('figure[class="df-card__image image"] > img'))
            const spans = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('figure[class="df-card__image image"] > span'))
            const prices = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div[class="df-card__pricing price"] > span[class="price-new"]'))
            return images.map((img, index) => ({
                title: img.alt,
                text: spans[index].innerText,
                url: img.src,
                price: prices[index].innerText.trim()
            }));
        });
        
        await browser.close();
        return Promise.resolve(titles);

    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}

url = 'https://farmacialoreto.it/#/dfclassic/query=800106585'

getData(url)
    .then((titles) => {
        console.log(titles);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Result

```
$ node get-data.js
[
  {
    title: 'Ruberkehl D5 10f 1ml Sanum',
    text: '-32%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/fiale.jpg',
    price: '68,46 €'
  }
]
```

[image]

Multiple product search

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function getData(ids) {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const total_titles = []
        for (let i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            url = `https://farmacialoreto.it/#/dfclassic/query=${ids[i]}`
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.goto(url);
            let titles = await page.evaluate((product_id) => {
                const images = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('figure[class="df-card__image image"] > img'))
                const spans = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('figure[class="df-card__image image"] > span'))
                const prices = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div[class="df-card__pricing price"] > span[class="price-new"]'))
                return images.map((img, index) => ({
                    title: img.alt,
                    product_id : product_id,
                    text: (spans[index].innerText == null) ? '' : spans[index].innerText.trim(),
                    url: img.src,
                    price: (prices[index].innerText == null) ? '' :prices[index].innerText.trim()
                }));
            }, ids[i]);
            if (titles.length > 0)
                total_titles.push(titles[0])
            console.log(ids[i]);
            await page.close();
        }
        await browser.close();
        return Promise.resolve(total_titles);
    } catch (error) {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
}

const ids = [
    030175020,
    800075590,
    800077125,
    800078685,
    800079434,
    800106585,
    800130573,
    800131017,
    800166769,
    800175008,
    800196824,
    800196851,
    800202501,
    800202855,
    800218505,
    800218594,
    800219457,
    800225904,
    800238457,
    800240246,
    800242190,
    800243331,
    800243432,
    800244384,
    800246225,
    800246643,
    800246656,
    800249308,
    800251504,
    800254219,
    800262572,
    800282636,
    800408155,
    800473997,
    800586048,
    800590299,
    800590655,
    800591620,
    800596037,
    800619239,
    800624482,
    800636351,
    800640880,
    800641375,
    800641817,
    800649966,
    800650196,
    800650804,
    800652291,
    800652859,
    800659120,
    800678587,
    800680478,
    800697649,
    800697690,
    800698108,
    800713493,
    800713505,
    800715866,
    800716021,
    800720118,
    800728382,
    800890889,
    800916684,
    801106461,
    801216831,
    801229598,
    801229636,
    801281864,
    801290382,
    801451345,
    801548518,
    801812013,
    802118430,
    900727379
]

getData(ids)
    .then((titles) => {
        console.log(titles);
    })
```

Result

```
[
  {
    title: 'Aurum Metallicum Praeparatum D30 Trituratium Weleda 20g',
    product_id: 800075590,
    text: '-5%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/aurum-metallicum-d30-weleda-20g.jpg',
    price: '22,52 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Quarz D30 Weleda 20g',
    product_id: 800077125,
    text: '-1%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/quarz-d30-weleda-polvere-20g.jpg',
    price: '22,97 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Plumbum Mellitum D12 Weleda 180 Tablets',
    product_id: 800078685,
    text: '-11%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/brands/WELEDA%20ITALIA%20Srl.jpg',
    price: '22,32 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Stibium Metallicum Preparatum D6 Weleda 8 Vials of 1ml',
    product_id: 800079434,
    text: '-17%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/stibium-metallicum-preparatum-d6-weleda-8fiale.jpg',
    price: '20,72 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Ruberkehl D5 10f 1ml Sanum',
    product_id: 800106585,
    text: '-32%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/fiale.jpg',
    price: '68,46 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Aqua Maris D3 / Prunus Spinosa Weleda 8 Vials of 1ml',
    product_id: 800130573,
    text: '-13%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/aqua-maris-prunus-spin-weleda-8fiale.jpg',
    price: '20,96 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Bryophyllum D5 / Conchae D7 Weleda 8 Vials of 1ml',
    product_id: 800131017,
    text: '-6%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/bryophyllum-d5-conchae-d7-weleda-8fiale.jpg',
    price: '22,28 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Solunat 14 Homeopathic Drops 50ml',
    product_id: 800166769,
    text: '-16%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/800166769.jpg',
    price: '17,26 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Detox 3 Connective Guna Drops 30ml',
    product_id: 800196824,
    text: '-18%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/Detox-3-Connettivo-Guna-Gocce-30ml.jpg',
    price: '11,14 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Detox 6 Load Emerg Guna Drops 30ml',
    product_id: 800196851,
    text: '-17%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/Detox-6-Carico-Emerg-Guna-Gocce-30ml.jpg',
    price: '11,30 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Vanda Renine Vanda Compositum® Food Supplement 40 Capsules',
    product_id: 800202501,
    text: '-1%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/800202501.jpg',
    price: '34,84 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Endocrinotox 3 Guna Drops 30ml',
    product_id: 800202855,
    text: '-17%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/Endocrinotox-3-Guna-Gocce-30ml.jpg',
    price: '12,14 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Unda Lachesis Mutus 200K 140 Globules',
    product_id: 800218505,
    text: '-12%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/800218505.jpg',
    price: '9,02 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Sepia Officinalis 200k Homeopathic Remedy In Globules',
    product_id: 800218594,
    text: '-7%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/umberto/cemon-550x669.png',
    price: '9,50 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Sepia Officinalis 60lm Homeopathic Globules',
    product_id: 800219457,
    text: '-17%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/800219457.png',
    price: '10,20 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Metatox 4 Guna Drops 30ml',
    product_id: 800225904,
    text: '-17%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/Metatox-4-Guna-Gocce-30ml.jpg',
    price: '12,90 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Chelidonium Majus 5ch Homeopathic Remedy In Granules',
    product_id: 800238457,
    text: '-12%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/umberto/cemon-550x669.png',
    price: '7,77 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Phosphoricum Acidum 6Ch Granules 6g',
    product_id: 800240246,
    text: '-18%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/brands/cemon.png',
    price: '7,26 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Cantharis 7ch Homeopathic Remedy In Granules',
    product_id: 800242190,
    text: '-12%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/umberto/cemon-550x669.png',
    price: '7,77 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Natrum Sulfuricum 15ch Homeopathic Remedy In Granules',
    product_id: 800243331,
    text: '-17%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/umberto/cemon-550x669.png',
    price: '7,37 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Muriaticum Acidum 30ch Homeopathic Remedy In Granules',
    product_id: 800243432,
    text: '-17%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/umberto/cemon-550x669.png',
    price: '7,14 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Iris Versicolor 30ch Homeopathic Remedy In Granules',
    product_id: 800244384,
    text: '-12%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/800024438.png',
    price: '7,77 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Luesinum 200Ch Cemon 140 Globuli',
    product_id: 800246225,
    text: '-10%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/catalog/products/108266/luesinum-200ch-cemon-140globuli.jpeg',
    price: '9,19 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Actaea Racemosa 200k Homeopathic Remedy In Globules',
    product_id: 800246643,
    text: '-17%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/umberto/cemon-550x669.png',
    price: '8,50 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Aesculus Hippocastanus 200k Homeopathic Remedy In Globules',
    product_id: 800246656,
    text: '-17%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/umberto/cemon-550x669.png',
    price: '8,50 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Hamamelis Virginiana Mk Globuli',
    product_id: 800249308,
    text: '-14%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/umberto/cemon-550x669.png',
    price: '8,80 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Belladonna 6lm Globules Homeopathic Remedy',
    product_id: 800251504,
    text: '-14%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/800251504.jpg',
    price: '10,56 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Natrium Sulfuricum Cure 6k-mk Homeopathic Remedy',
    product_id: 800254219,
    text: '-9%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/umberto/cemon-550x669.png',
    price: '22,14 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Agaricus Muscarius 9ch Homeopathic Remedy In Granules',
    product_id: 800262572,
    text: '-17%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/umberto/cemon-550x669.png',
    price: '7,14 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Trikoplus HERING Lotion 120ml',
    product_id: 800282636,
    text: '-1%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/trikoplus-lozione-hering-120ml.jpg',
    price: '24,75 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Boiron Rana Bufo 200ch Granules Homeopathic Remedy',
    product_id: 800408155,
    text: '-40%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/800408155.jpg',
    price: '4,74 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Flurin HERING Nasal Spray 15ml',
    product_id: 800473997,
    text: '-40%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/flurin-hering-spray-nasale-15ml.jpg',
    price: '7,56 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Bellaplex Guna Granules 4g',
    product_id: 800586048,
    text: '-17%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/Bellaplex-Guna-Granuli-4g.jpg',
    price: '9,97 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Oti Prodif Homeopathic Remedy In Drops 50ml',
    product_id: 800590299,
    text: '-19%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/catalog/products/214156/prodif-composto-oti-50ml.jpeg',
    price: '14,51 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Tetraferrum Compound Oti 50ml',
    product_id: 800590655,
    text: '-21%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/catalog/products/214170/tetraferrum-composto-oti-50ml.jpeg',
    price: '14,23 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Oti Otirin Nasal Spray 20ml',
    product_id: 800591620,
    text: '-18%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/products/800591620.jpg',
    price: '12,33 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Echinacea Forte OTI 50ml range',
    product_id: 800596037,
    text: '-8%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/catalog/products/214214/gamma-echinacea-forte-oti-50ml.jpeg',
    price: '25,47 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Argentum Metallicum Preparatum D30 Weleda 20g',
    product_id: 800619239,
    text: '-5%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/argentum-metallicum-praep-d30-weleda-20g.jpg',
    price: '22,52 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Hypericum Perf Cure 6k-mk',
    product_id: 800624482,
    text: '-13%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/umberto/cemon-550x669.png',
    price: '21,12 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'UNDA Antimonium Tartaricum 15CH Globules Homeopathic Medicine',
    product_id: 800636351,
    text: '-14%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/800636351.jpg',
    price: '7,06 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Apis Mellifica 6ch Homeopathic Drops 10ml',
    product_id: 800640880,
    text: '-17%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/800640880.png',
    price: '11,03 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Arsenicum Album 30lm Homeopathic Remedy In Drops 10ml',
    product_id: 800641375,
    text: '-15%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/umberto/cemon-550x669.png',
    price: '17,29 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Belladonna 30ch Drops 10ml',
    product_id: 800641817,
    text: '-13%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/800641817.jpg',
    price: '11,60 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Sepia Officinalis 200k Homeopathic Remedy Drops 10ml',
    product_id: 800649966,
    text: '-8%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/800649966.jpg',
    price: '12,16 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Silicea 18lm Drops 10ml',
    product_id: 800650196,
    text: '-13%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/umberto/cemon-550x669.png',
    price: '17,74 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Thuya Occidentalis Xmk Drops 10ml',
    product_id: 800650804,
    text: '-6%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/800650804.jpg',
    price: '12,54 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Nitricum Acidum 200k Granules 5g',
    product_id: 800652291,
    text: '-20%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/800652291.jpg',
    price: '9,70 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Aconitum Napellus 200K Granules 6g',
    product_id: 800652859,
    text: '-23%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/800652859.jpg',
    price: '9,32 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Calcium Fluoratum 30lm Gr',
    product_id: 800659120,
    text: '-14%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/brands/cemon.png',
    price: '14,96 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Cupressus Sempervirens 5ch Homeopathic Remedy In Granules',
    product_id: 800678587,
    text: '-17%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/umberto/cemon-550x669.png',
    price: '7,14 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Unda Lachesis Mutus Mk Granulate 140 Granules 6g',
    product_id: 800697649,
    text: '-23%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/800697649.jpg',
    price: '9,34 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Unda Lachesis Mutus 200k Granules 140 Granules 6g',
    product_id: 800697690,
    text: '-15%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/800697690.jpg',
    price: '10,27 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Ledum Palustre 15ch Homeopathic Remedy In Granules',
    product_id: 800698108,
    text: '-20%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/umberto/cemon-550x669.png',
    price: '7,09 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Unda Silicea 200k Granules 6g',
    product_id: 800713493,
    text: '-7%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/800713493.jpg',
    price: '11,18 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Silicea 18lm Granulated 6g',
    product_id: 800713505,
    text: '-15%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/brands/cemon.png',
    price: '14,72 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Thuya Occidentalis 6lm Cemon Granules',
    product_id: 800715866,
    text: '-20%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/catalog/products/108813/thuya-occidentalis-6lm-cemon-granuli.jpeg',
    price: '13,92 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Thyroidinum 5ch Cemon Granules',
    product_id: 800716021,
    text: '-6%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/catalog/products/215414/thyroidinum-5ch-cemon-granuli.jpeg',
    price: '8,29 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Candida Albicans Mk Homeopathic Remedy In Blood Cells',
    product_id: 800720118,
    text: '-22%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/umberto/cemon-550x669.png',
    price: '7,98 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Mercurius Solubilis 30ch Homeopathic Remedy In Globules',
    product_id: 800728382,
    text: '-20%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/umberto/cemon-550x669.png',
    price: '6,63 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Argentum Metallicum 30ch Food Supplement Globules',
    product_id: 800890889,
    text: '-8%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/800890889.jpg',
    price: '7,55 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Lachesis Mutus 12lm Gr',
    product_id: 800916684,
    text: '-12%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/brands/cemon.png',
    price: '15,20 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Aluminasup HERING 10 Suppositories',
    product_id: 801106461,
    text: '-5%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/aluminasup-hering-10-supposte.jpg',
    price: '10,93 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Allium Cepa 200ch Granules 6g',
    product_id: 801216831,
    text: '-20%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/801216831.jpg',
    price: '10,92 €'
  },
  {
    title: "Linda's Lab Cel 21 Drops 30ml",
    product_id: 801229598,
    text: '-3%',
    url: "https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/brands/LINDA'S%20LAB.%20OMEOPATICI.jpg",
    price: '14,57 €'
  },
  {
    title: "Linda's Lab Cartila 23 Drops 30ml",
    product_id: 801229636,
    text: '-5%',
    url: "https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/brands/LINDA'S%20LAB.%20OMEOPATICI.jpg",
    price: '14,25 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Cemon Medorrhinum Xmk Homeopathic Granules',
    product_id: 801281864,
    text: '-17%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/801281864.png',
    price: '10,03 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Olitoti Zinc Copper OTI 20 Glucosate Vials',
    product_id: 801290382,
    text: '-12%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/catalog/products/200641/olitoti-zn-cu-oti-20x2ml.png',
    price: '22,04 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Thuyaplus HERING Homeoderm Cream 50g',
    product_id: 801451345,
    text: '-5%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/thuyaplus-crema-homeoderm-hering-50g.jpg',
    price: '11,40 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Imo Influenzinum 9ch Homeopathic Remedy 4 Single-dose Tubes of 1g',
    product_id: 801548518,
    text: '-8%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/801548518.png',
    price: '17,43 €'
  },
  {
    title: "Linda's Lab Procalin 12 Vials",
    product_id: 801812013,
    text: '-5%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/data/801812013.jpg',
    price: '23,75 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Prunus S Ferm C Ferro Gl',
    product_id: 802118430,
    text: '-5%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/catalog/products/228220/prunus-s-ferm-c-ferro-wala-globuli-20g%20-%20Copia.jpg',
    price: '15,67 €'
  },
  {
    title: 'Natur Elm Floral Essence 10ml',
    product_id: 900727379,
    text: '-1%',
    url: 'https://farmacialoreto.it/image/catalog/products/229091/elm-bach-flower-remedies-healing-herbs-10ml.jpg',
    price: '11,84 €'
  }
]
```

*Note - it's number of products has limit 75, due to unknow issues.
You needs to spite  groups if more than 75.

Comment: @Ax_, I re-updated my code from your code. It would be better single code. then two sources.

Comment: @Ax_, I attached multiple product search. The authenticated issue is different topic, I can't figure out without credential.